# How do I include output parameters in my Postgres PLpgsql stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a stored procedure which was written in SQL Server before.
It took a couple of output parameters.
I am trying to include the same in postgresSQL stored procedure but I am facing the following issues.

Sample Code:

```
CREATE procedure poii(
   VARIADIC list NUMERIC[]
   out res int
 )
AS $$
BEGIN
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The output is giving the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "out"
> LINE 3:  out res int
>          ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 52
> ```

I do not wish to use functions due to some requirements.
Please help me get a way around this.

Comment: You're missing a comma after the first parameter.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you want to return something use a function. Procedures aren't meant for that (despite some common usage in other DBMS products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) says:

> `OUT` arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use `INOUT` instead.

This might be implemented in a later versions.

But you don't need that. If you want code that takes arguments and returns a value, a function is the natura way to express that:

```
CREATE function poii(VARIADIC list NUMERIC[]) RETURNS int ...
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am avoiding the use of functions, as I might need to migrate to SQL server where we will be using stored procedure over functions.